# GCC : weird errors with -O0, none without

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, compiler-optimization, rtos

I'd like to compile my C code without optimisations, but when I add the -O0 option to the compilation command I get lots of "multiple definitions" errors, of functions I didn't even write ! I guess there's something obvious I'm missing here but as a noob I just can't figure out what...

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N       1800

unsigned long int tsec, tnsec;

int main(void)
{
        int err, i;
        printf("started\n");

        struct timespec tps, tpe, req, rem;

        req.tv_nsec = 400000;
        req.tv_sec = 0;

        struct sched_param param;
        param.sched_priority = 99;
        err = sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_FIFO, &param);
        if (err != 0)
                printf("sched_setscheduler error");
        err = sched_getparam(getpid(), &param);
        if (err != 0)
                printf("sched_getparam error");
        printf("priority = %i\n", param.sched_priority);

        int policy = sched_getscheduler(getpid());
        printf("policy = %i\n", policy);


        sleep(1);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tps);

        #include "noppynop2.c"
        #include "noppynop2.c"
        #include "noppynop2.c"
        #include "noppynop2.c"
        #include "noppynop2.c"
        #include "noppynop2.c"


        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe);
        tnsec = tpe.tv_nsec - tps.tv_nsec;
        tsec = tpe.tv_sec - tps.tv_sec;
        printf("time = %lu sec %lu nsec\n", tsec, tnsec);


        printf("finished\n");

        return 0;
}
```

To sum thing up, it's a bruteforce attempt to create a delay on a real-time kernel's Linux. "noppynop2.c" contains 500 times asm("nop"). I don't think this is the problem here but that's the context. The code is mostly just a test, and I want to get rid of all optimisations because for the moment the compiler tends to remove an (apparently) unpredictable quantity of "nops", which is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do...

When I compile without the -O0 option, everything goes fine :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/Projects/test_timemeasure_sched $ gcc -Wall -o test_time_measure_sched main.c -lwiringPi -lpthread -lrt
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:22:33: warning: unused variable ‘rem’ [-Wunused-variable]
main.c:22:28: warning: variable ‘req’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
main.c:19:11: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

But when I add the -O0 here's what I get :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/Projects/test_timemeasure_sched $ gcc -Wall -o -O0 test_time_measure_sched main.c -lwiringPi -lpthread -lrt
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:22:33: warning: unused variable ‘rem’ [-Wunused-variable]
main.c:22:28: warning: variable ‘req’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
main.c:19:11: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
test_time_measure_sched: In function `_fini':
:(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
test_time_measure_sched: In function `__data_start':
:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
test_time_measure_sched: In function `__data_start':
:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
test_time_measure_sched:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
test_time_measure_sched: In function `_start':
:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
test_time_measure_sched: In function `_init':
:(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc5At86c.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
test_time_measure_sched::(.text+0xac): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could I do to get rid of those errors ?

Thanx in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Eric

Comment: The `-o` option is at the wrong place. Keep `-o test_time_measure_sched` together.

Comment: `"noppynop2.c" contains 500 times asm("nop")` - is that *all* it contains?  Can you post a snippet of it?

Comment: @JohnBode : yes it only contains 500 times asm("nop"), nothing more, nothing less ;)

Comment: @SisterFister : that solved the problem, thank you so much !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gcc command should be

```
gcc -Wall -O0 -o test_time_measure_sched main.c -lwiringPi -lpthread -lrt
```

instead of

```
gcc -Wall -o -O0 test_time_measure_sched main.c -lwiringPi -lpthread -lrt
```

With the second command the old binary `test_time_measure_sched` is treated as an input file by gcc. The additional errors you are getting are all linker errors, which indicates that gcc tries to link the old binary to your new code.

Comment: Quibble: gcc is clearly not treating the old binary as C code -- it would surely report tons of compilation errors if it tried to do so; instead, it fails at the link stage.  But it may very well be trying to *link* the old binary into the new one.  That would be entirely consistent with the several link errors it emits.

Comment: Switching places between -o and -O0 solved the problem, thank you very much folks !

BTW I still get my asm("nop") optimised out, but that would be another topic !

Comment: You probably need "asm volatile".  Also see if asm( "nop" : ) makes any difference.